# Integral of the quotient between exponential and sum of exponentials

Tags: integration

How can the following integral be calculated?

$$\int \frac{K(f_i,f_p)}{\sum_j K(f_j,f_p)} df_p$$, with $K(f_1,f_2)= e^{-||f_1-f_2||^2}$.

$\forall i, f_i$ id some $d$ dimensional vector (for the sake of this answer, we can also consider it a one-dimensional variable).

I am no mathematician, I apologize if my formulation is unprecise.

Comment: What is the domain of integration?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that $f_i$ is one of the $f_j$s in the denominator. If so, by factoring through by $K(f_i, f_p),$ you get an integral of the form

$$\int \frac{1}{1+\sum a_i \exp(b_i x)} d x.$$ (in one dimension, that is). This generally does not converge on the real line, and the indefinite integral has an easy closed form where the sum has one term, and no closed form when it has more.